# I now realize my question was unanswerable. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

This morning I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287304/can-a-c-sharp-event-handler-be-deferred-until-after-other-handlers-have-been-cal/) and received a few helpful comments, but no answers. I later realized that the source of my problem was not visible in the code I posted in the question. I went ahead and posted my solution and marked it as community wiki to prevent earning reputation for my own oversight. Should I do more, though?

Comment: @Will Thanks for for fixing the link. I thought copy-paste from the page I was looking at would be the right link. Now I see the pattern: `/:id/:url_encoded_question`.

Comment: That's a mistake lots of people have been making here, which is hitting some weird corner-case button of mine :(  Hate clicking to read a question and having to scroll up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the solution to the problem required knowledge not in the question then fundamentally the question is "unclear".

There is one real solution to this particular problem.  You can **edit the question** so that it *does* contain enough information to be answerable (in addition to answering it).

Now, with many of these types of questions it just so happens that they also are localized to really just be an issue for you.  It's not always the case, but you should take a moment to ask yourself if the question, along with the answer, is likely to actually *help someone else*.  If it is, then it's worth taking the time to edit the question to accurately describe your actual problem (so that people can actually find the question and determine if their problem is the same), and then to provide an answer to that problem (so that they can actually solve their problem).  If nobody would actually benefit from that, then don't waste your time/effort, and just delete the question.

Providing an answer without also editing the question isn't terribly helpful, because as it is the question doesn't describe your actual problem.  Someone else with the same problem is very unlikely to find your question when searching, and if they did, then when they read it they'd see that it's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to add the relevant bit.

Answer (score 7):

Questions that stay on Stack Overflow should be of benefit to at least one other programmer.  You'll have to decide whether or not yours has such a benefit.

If it doesn't, there's a delete link right below the question, assuming nobody's posted an upvoted answer to your question.

Comment: There's also voting to close your own question as off-topic, no longer reproducible, given the privilege.