# Deleting question later after I found the answer was just stupidity

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a question that I thought was general. After a couple comments and some further experimentation, I later realized that the problem was very isolated. The fix to the problem was already obvious to me and **doesn't really relate to or answer the original question**.

In my mind, the right answer to the original question is "Well that's not actually a problem, your just stupid and need to do more testing".

I am debating deleting the question altogether. Should I delete the question, or should I let it just sit there unanswered forever?

For reference, here is the question:
[Install pyyaml using pip/Add PyYaml as pip dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791251/install-pyyaml-using-pip-add-pyyaml-as-pip-dependency)

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've had enough of those myself. Leave it up and add your answer detailing the actual cause and the solution. Worst case: nothing happens; best case: your situation might be found interesting or you might even give someone that hint to his own problem.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Honestly, your comments sounds best to me. If you want to add it as an answer i can flag it for you

Comment: Sort of similar to my question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260920/i-now-realize-my-question-was-unanswerable-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 8):

If the question is going to be of no value to anyone who might come across it, delete it and save them from wasting the time of reading it.

If you think that there could be value to other people in having an answer to the question then don't delete the question and optionally post an answer to it.