# I realised that my question is unanswerable. should I close it or delete it?

Tags: discussion

I posted [Disabling certificate health check in spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326427/disabling-certificate-health-check-in-spring-boot-application) a while back. I have since realized that the issue was a custom health check included in a custom spring-starter package in my organization.

In essence, this question cannot be answered, and I fail to see any advantage of keeping it active in SO.

So my question is: what should I do with it?

- Should I delete it?
- Should I vote it closed?
- Should I add my findings (as described above) as my answer, to potentially help others who have a similar spring boot setup in their organization to get an "Aha" moment?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: As per this post: [Robert Harvey's answer to "I now realize my question was unanswerable. What should I do?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260922/7795130), the guideline is "Questions that stay on Stack Overflow should be of benefit to at least one other programmer. You'll have to decide whether or not yours has such a benefit."

Comment: If it’s reusable, people will actually encounter this, and not some crazy corner case unlikely to ever recur, answer it (thoroughly, as you would have liked to been answer by a magical all-knowing oracle if you could have been). If it’s not, delete it. Closure doesn’t buy you anything and depends on others.

Comment: Yeah, delete or answer and keep; closing is ultimately pointless here, it just leads to [xkcd.com/979/](https://xkcd.com/979/)-moments. I'm sure there's room for it in the database if there's even the smallest chance that your answer can benefit someone else later.